# Cannot Read JSON request body parameters in wso2 ESB as an api

Tags: json, wso2, jsonpath, wso2-esb

I have created an API in the WSO2 ESB (4.8.1) and I wanted to send a PUT request to that API with a request body. I have tried with the [sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JSON+Support) 
and I wanted to log a property values in the insequence of the defined API.

This is my request body:

[image: request body (JSON)]

This is the way how I tried to log the location name:

[image: XML log]

But I’m getting an error like this:

> (ERROR - SynapseJsonPath #stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path . Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path)

[image: error screenshot]

So how can I read these values?

Comment: Since the images you posted show text only, you probably should edit your question to include the actual text, so that both request and errors become searchable.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I have taken the request from the given link in my question. When i'm trying to post as a text getting an error saying that my code to be formatted. that is why I added a print screen

Comment: can you confirm that $. print in the log the full JSON payload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, you should send the "Content-Type" HTTP header with the request like below,

```
    "Content-Type : application/json"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96kSH.png)

Then you can log the specific JSON element like below.

```
 <log>
    <property name="location" expression="json-eval($.coordinates.location[0].name)"></property>
 </log>
```

Then you can see following log,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMnmc.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to get single variable from user in json request you can use this code 


Use This json:
    {

    "namee":"UsmanYaqooooooooooob"
    }


Api Code: 
        <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Hello" context="/hello">
           <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/post">
              <inSequence>
                 <log level="custom">
                    <property name="===========inSequence" value="****"></property>
                    <property name="locationsssssssss" expression="json-eval(.namee)"></property>
                 </log>
                 <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                    <format>{"hello":"world"}</format>
                    <args></args>
                 </payloadFactory>
                 <property name="messageType" value="text/xml"></property>
                 <respond></respond>
              </inSequence>
           </resource>
        </api>
```